# Meteor.js iron:router server route triggers RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, meteor, stripe-payments, iron-router, webhooks

I am working on setting up a Stripe webhook route on my server and have copied the code directly from the readme for iron router but when I send test webhooks from stripe to my server I get the RangeError.

I have my route defined like this:

```
Router.route('/webhooks/stripe', { where: 'server' })
.get(function () {
    // GET /webhooks/stripe
    console.log("Get request from stripe")
})
.post(function () {
    // POST /webhooks/stripe
    console.log("Received POST Webhook from Stripe");
    console.log(this);

    this.response.end('webhook ended');
})
.put(function () {
    // PUT /webhooks/stripe
    console.log("Put request from stripe")
})
```

I have also tried defining the route like this:

```
Router.map(function(){
this.route("webhooks", {layoutTemplate:null, path:'/webhooks/stripe', where:"server"}).post(function () {
    // POST /webhooks/stripe
    console.log("Received POST Webhook from Stripe");
    console.log(this);
    // // NodeJS  response object
    // var response = this.response;

    this.response.end('webhook ended');
})
})
```

I am using ultrahook to forward the test webhooks to my local development machine. I don't get any console output except the above error printed a single time.
I have also tried to hit the endpoint using the Chrome extension Postman and I receive the same error.

UPDATED:
Also tried this for the route definition with no change

```
Router.route('/webhooks/stripe', function () {
    var req = this.request;
    var res = this.response;
    res.end('hello from the server\n');
}, {where: 'server'});
```

I have to be doing something wrong but I have not been able to find an example that does work for me. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `Maximum call stack size exceeded` almost always come from runaway recursive calls. Watch for that too!

Comment: Yeah I know that is the normal cause but in this case the request does not even seem to be hitting my route before it throws that error. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I spent forever looking at this before I posted this and it turns out that I really just needed to change my onBeforeAction calls to exclude the server routes.

I had

```
Router.onBeforeAction(requireLogin, {except:["home"]});
```

and I needed to change it to

```
Router.onBeforeAction(requireLogin, {except:["home", "webhooks"]});
```

My requireLogin method looks like this:

```
var requireLogin = function() {

    if (! Meteor.user()) {
        if (Meteor.loggingIn()) {
            this.render(this.loadingTemplate);
        }else{
            Router.go('/');
            this.next();
        }
    } else {
        this.next();
    }
};
```